# How can I turn this array structure into this other pattern?

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, design-patterns

**From this:**

`[["a", "b"], ["a", "c"], ["a", "d"], ["d", "e"], ["d", "f"], ["f", "g"]]`

**To this:**

`[["a", "b"], ["a", "c"], ["a", "d", "e"], ["a", "d", "f", "g"]]`

The first element of each inner array represents a "father" and the second one a "son", so the final goal is to find grandsons, grandgrandsons... and then group them in bigger arrays, where all descendants are together.

Maybe it's an easy task, but I've been struggling to figure out how to get it!

Comment: why adf? wh not take adfg only?

Comment: There is no clean logic in transformation you have provided

Comment: @NinaScholz Sorry, the adf array was incorrect, I have removed it!

Comment: I came up with a neat recursive answer, but now the question is closed. Was going to post it but now the question is closed!!

Comment: @re-za Would be nice to see that solution! They close my question, so the only way to do it is in the comments :/

Answer (score 1):

If you like to get all relations, without parts which are included in other results, you could get an object of all descendant and start with the parents who are not having parents.

```js
let
    getNodes = k => parents[k]
        ? parents[k].flatMap(getNodes).map(a => [k, ...a])
        : [[k]],
    data = [["a", "b"], ["a", "c"], ["a", "d"], ["d", "e"], ["d", "f"], ["f", "g"]],
    parents = {},
    children = new Set,
    result;


for (const [p, c] of data) {
    (parents[p] ??= []).push(c);
    children.add(c);
}

result = Object
    .keys(parents)
    .filter(p => !children.has(p))
    .flatMap(getNodes);

result.map(a => console.log(...a));
```

Comment: if I change the data variable to arrays containing longer strings, like [['Jack', 'Louis'],['Jack', 'Daniel'],['Daniel', 'David']] , the result is broken:
=>  "Jack" "L" "o" "u" "i" "s"
=> "Jack" "Daniel" "D" "a" "v" "i" "d"

. How could we fix this?

Comment: please try now.

Comment: Awesome, it works perfectly! You truly are a JavaScript master. Thank you so much!